# How can ActiveSheet, ActiveWorkbook or ThisWorkbook be set as the default for an optional parameter in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, properties, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I am trying to set the default value of an optional parameter to Excel's `Application.ActiveWorkbook` property.  Here is my failed attempt:

### Attempted Code

```
Function SheetExists(ByVal sheetName As String, _
    Optional ByVal targetBook As Workbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook) As Boolean
```

### Result

This code caused a

> Constant expression required : compile error

### Questions

1. What is a "Constant Expression"?
2. Is there another way to use the `ActiveWorkbook` property (and other properties) as default values of parameters in functions and subroutines?

Comment: 1. A constant expression is one that the compiler can deduce before the code is compiled.  `optional x = 5` is fine as `5` is a constant, the compiler can generate code that assigns `5` to `x` if `x` is missing, it can't do that with non-constant values as they can contain different values at runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you use something like this:

```
Public function SheetExists(ByVal sheetName As String, Optional wb As Workbook)

  If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb =  Application.ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook

  'your code here, for example
  wb.Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic 
End Sub
```